# Delphi Adoquery SQL add or text

Tags: delphi-7

I'm trying to update my database in Delphi, but I'm not getting it right.

What I want is simple. This is my code:

```
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Update Table1 set mark=' +Form1.Edit4.Text);
form1.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

So basically, what I want is the Text written in the Edit to go into my database with the `UPDATE` function, where my database table is `table1` and the field is named `mark`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the actual data type of the `mark` field? And what kind of values are you entering into `Edit4`?  It makes a big difference in how the SQL needs to be formatted.

Comment: Why are you using a text field for a boolean-like value?  By not just us an actual byte/bool type instead? Or at least an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not enough information in your question to provide a definitive answer.  However, I can make an estimated guess.

What you have shown would only work successfully if `mark` is defined as an ordinal or boolean field, and the user is entering appropriate numeric/boolean values into the `TEdit`.

But, if the `mark` field is defined as a textual field instead, you need to wrap the `Text` value in quote characters, otherwise you will produce invalid SQL syntax.

Imagine you entered a `Text` value of `'hello world'`.  Your original SQL statement would end up being the following, which is invalid syntax:

```
Update Table1 set mark=hello world
```

You need to wrap text values in quote characters instead:

```
Update Table1 set mark='hello world'
```

Or:

```
Update Table1 set mark="hello world"
```

For example:

```
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Update Table1 set mark=' + QuotedStr(Form1.Edit4.Text));
```

Or:

```
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Update Table1 set mark=' + AnsiQuotedStr(Form1.Edit4.Text, #34));
```

It is important to use a function like `(Ansi)QuotedStr()` to avoid SQL injection attacks.  This is done by ensuring any embedded quote characters in the input text are escaped property.  Otherwise, if you just did something like this instead:

```
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Update Table1 set mark="' + Form1.Edit4.Text + '"');
```

The user could enter a text value like `'"; <arbitrary SQL here>'` and really reek havoc with your database.

The safer approach is to use a **parameterized query** instead, and let ADO handle any necessary SQL formatting for you (make sure `TADOQuery.ParamCheck` is true):

```
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Update Table1 set mark=:Mark');
form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Mark').Value := Form1.Edit4.Text;
form1.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: 1+ for using functions like (Ansi)QuotedStr() to avoid SQL injection attacks.