# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression - Delphi

Tags: ms-access, delphi

I'm Receiving a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression as seen Below.

[image: Error Box in Delphi]

Please can anyone assist, Code Runs well except when I Update a specific "Request".

```
qryRequests.Close;
qryRequests.SQL.Clear;
qryRequests.SQL.Add('Update tblRequest SET State = "' + cmbStates.Text + '"');
qryRequests.SQL.Add('Update tblRequest SET AssignmentGroup = "' + cmbAssignmentF.Text + '"');
qryRequests.SQL.Add('WHERE RequestNumber = "' + edtREQNum.Text + '"');
qryRequests.ExecSQL;
qryRequests.Close;
qryRequests.SQL.Clear;
qryRequests.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblRequest');
qryRequests.Open;
```

I have tried, adding the "QuoteStr" to see if that would solve the problem however, it only created more.

Comment: Add an ``;`` at the end of the first update SQL statement.

Comment: Hi Dont understand what you mean, there is one at the end.

Comment: Inside the SQL string, not at the end of the Delphi command: ``qryRequests.SQL.Add('Update tblRequest SET State = "' + cmbStates.Text + '";');``

Comment: Thank you Syntax error is gone, I now get an error "Characters found after end of SQL Statement"

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL syntax is not correct. Just to add to the perfect answer @June7 provided you can use parameters in your SQL. This prevents sql injection and also allows the code to be more readable.

```pascal
qryRequests.Close;
qryRequests.SQL.Clear;

// Enable Param check
qryRequests.ParamCheck := True;

// Build SQL Query with params
qryRequests.SQL.Add('Update tblRequest SET State = :aState, '); //<-- Notice the comma
qryRequests.SQL.Add('AssignmentGroup = :aAssignmentGroup ');
qryRequests.SQL.Add('WHERE RequestNumber = :aReqNum');

// Assign Values to Params
qryRequests.ParamByName('aState').Value := cmbStates.Text;
qryRequests.ParamByName('aAssignmentGroup').Value := cmbAssignmentF.Text;
qryRequests.ParamByName('aReqNum').Value := edtREQNum.Text;

// Execute
qryRequests.ExecSQL;

qryRequests.Close;
qryRequests.SQL.Clear;
qryRequests.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblRequest');
qryRequests.Open;
```

Comment: this is the only correct solution, always use parameters!

Answer (score 1):

A semi-colon is not necessary for programmatic execution of SQL, although Access query designer will add them. Access cannot execute multiple SQL queries in one statement. I presume you want to update both fields for only records matching RequestNumber. Be sure to code in a space in front of WHERE or at end of previous line so the concatenated parts don't run together when compiled. If SQL injection is a concern, review [Delphi Adoquery SQL add or text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396960/delphi-adoquery-sql-add-or-text)

```
qryRequests.SQL.Add('Update tblRequest SET State = "' + cmbStates.Text + '", ');
qryRequests.SQL.Add('AssignmentGroup = "' + cmbAssignmentF.Text + '" ');
qryRequests.SQL.Add('WHERE RequestNumber = "' + edtREQNum.Text + '"');
```

Use apostrophe delimiters if fields are text type, none if numeric, # delimiter for date/time fields.

BTW, if both of those UPDATE actions could have executed, the result would be to update every record with the same State value and only records matching RequestNumber would update for AssignmentGroup. If that is actually what you want, then will have to execute two separate UPDATE actions.